# How to add add additonal ip to a Network Interface Card in azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a set of Private Ip address that i want to add to a Nic in Azure. I am running into error on adding the IP's to Nic.

```
set-AzContext -subscription "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name "rosvnet" -ResourceGroupName "sample"
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "default" -VirtualNetwork $vnet


$Nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName "sample" -Name "closer-nic"


$Nic | New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig1" -PrivateIpAddress "10.1.0.11" -Subnet $subnet
$Nic | New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig2" -PrivateIpAddress "10.1.0.13" -Subnet $subnet
$Nic | New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig2" -PrivateIpAddress "10.1.0.14" -Subnet $subnet


Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $Nic
```

error is:
New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not
match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
set-AzContext -subscription "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name "rosvnet" -ResourceGroupName "sample"
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "default" -VirtualNetwork $vnet



$Nic1 = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig1" -PrivateIpAddress "10.1.0.11" -Primary -Subnet $subnet
$Nic2 = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig2" -PrivateIpAddress "10.1.0.13" -Subnet $subnet
$Nic3 = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig2" -PrivateIpAddress "10.1.0.14" -Subnet $subnet

    

$NIC = New-AzNetworkInterface `
-Name MyNIC `
-ResourceGroupName  `
-Location  `
-NetworkSecurityGroupId  `
-IpConfiguration $Nic1,$Nic2,$Nic3
```

Comment: If i am deploying the first IP as well it throws an error saying its in use. I need a way to bypass the first ip as its going to be present and add the rest. If i try adding the rest it throws an error saying add one of the ip's as primary.

Comment: azure reserve 5 ip address in subnet. first 4 ip and last ip in subnet are reserved.

Comment: @user2838404 I updated the answer and you need to use -Primary flag with one ip address